# Difficulty with Responsiveness: Details and Image Grid Layout

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm encountering difficulties achieving the desired responsiveness for a grid layout that includes details and an image. On desktop screens, the layout appears as intended, with the details displayed on the left and the image on the right. However, on mobile screens, the image appears below the details, which is not the desired behavior.

Here's the code structure I'm working with:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Box, Paper, useMediaQuery, useTheme, Typography, Grid, Container,
} from '@mui/material';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import FormGroup from '@mui/material/FormGroup';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import LocationOnIcon from './SVGiCON';

export const CarInfo: React.FC = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    gilad: false,
    jason: false,
    antoine: false,
  });

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
    });
  };

  const { gilad, jason, antoine } = state;
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<number | null>(2);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Box
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="center"
        minHeight="100vh"
      >
        <Paper
          elevation={3}
          sx={{
            p: '1.5rem', // Use rem units
            borderRadius: '1.25rem', // Use rem units
            textAlign: 'center',
            maxWidth: isMobile ? '100%' : 'xl',
            width: '68.75rem', // Use rem units
            backgroundColor: 'grey !important',
            overflow: 'hidden', // Ensure the container doesn't overflow
          }}
        >
          <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6} style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
              {/* Details */}
              <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom color={'white'}>
                Car Title
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left">
                Собственик{' '}
                <Link to="/home" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', marginLeft: '0.625rem' }}>
                  <span style={{
                    color: 'black', backgroundColor: 'green', borderRadius: '1.25rem', padding: '0.625rem',
                  }}>
                    Александър Иванов
                  </span>
                </Link>
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem', marginTop: '1.25rem', marginBottom: '1.25rem' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '0.625rem', width: '0.9375rem', height: '0.9375rem' }} />
                Костинброд, София-област
              </Typography>

              {/* Other details */}
              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '0.625rem', width: '0.9375rem', height: '0.9375rem' }} />
                Бензин
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '0.625rem', width: '0.9375rem', height: '0.9375rem' }} />
                Черен
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '0.625rem', width: '0.9375rem', height: '0.9375rem' }} />
                2022 г.
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '0.625rem', width: '0.9375rem', height: '0.9375rem' }} />
                90 000 км
              </Typography>

              <FormGroup style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem', marginTop: '0.6875rem' }}>
                <FormControlLabel
                  style={{ marginBottom: '-0.625rem', color: "black" }}
                  control={
                    <Checkbox
                      checked={gilad}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      name="gilad"
                      size='small'
                      style={{ color: 'black' }} />
                  }
                  label="Реален пробег"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  style={{ color: "black" }}
                  control={
                    <Checkbox checked={jason}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      name="jason"
                      size='small'
                      style={{ color: 'black' }} />
                  }
                  label="Първи собственик"
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
              {/* Photo */}
              <div style={{ maxWidth: '100%', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                <img
                  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
                  alt="Car"
                  style={{
                    width: '100%', // Ensures the image is responsive
                    height: 'auto', // Ensures aspect ratio is maintained
                    display: 'block', // Ensures the image doesn't have any extra spacing issues
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CarInfo;
```

This is how it looks right now on the phone:
[image: This is how it looks right now on the phone]

This is how it ПКЯШ looks on the phone:

[image: This is how it MUST looks on the phone]

I've tried adjusting the grid layout and applying responsive styles, but the image continues to appear below the details on mobile screens. I'm aiming for a layout where both the details and the image remain side by side on larger screens and stack appropriately on smaller screens.

Any suggestions or insights on how to achieve the desired responsiveness for this grid layout would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue I caught at a glance over this code is that the grid layout configuration.

```
<Grid item xs={6} style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
```

Try to modify those grid items like this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately, it is not working!

Comment: Have you changed the second grid item as well so that it has only `xs={6}`?

Comment: I replaced the second grid item with the line that you sent, but it is not working. :)

Comment: The second item should be only like this: `<Grid item xs={6}>`
And I think it needs to add `direction='row-reverse'` in the grid container as well.
If this does not work, share the screen shot again...

Comment: How about to start a discussion?  Do you mind?